# Firebase Cloud Storage Java Admin SDK upload file with contentType

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm able to upload files on Google Cloud Storage using Firebase Admin SDK. However, I'm unable to set the correct contentType for the file and the uploaded file defaults to `application/octet-stream`. I'm unable to any documentations for setting the correct contentType/metadata using Java Admin SDK. How I can change the default contentType?

Here's the code snippet on how I upload the file.

```java
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
String timestamp = dateFormat.format(date);
StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.getInstance();
Bucket storageBucket = storageClient.bucket();

// Not sure if I'm doing this correctly
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(storageBucket.getName(), "filename")
        .setContentType("vnd.ms-excel").build();

// File upload task
storageClient.bucket().create(backupFolderPath + fileNamePrefix + "_" + timestamp + ".csv", file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I need to use [Google Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample). The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) for Firebase Cloud Storage for Admin SDK is barren. I hope that the docs were clearer.

Here's the snippet on how I modified the contentType for my file upload. This changed the contentType from `application/octet-stream` to `text/csv`

```java
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
String timestamp = dateFormat.format(date);
StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.getInstance();

try {
  String bucketName = "<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>";
  String objectName = backupFolderPath + fileNamePrefix + "_" + timestamp + ".csv";
  BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName);
  
  // Configure BlobInfo
  BlobInfo blob = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId)
      .setContentType("text/csv")
      .setContentEncoding("utf-8").build();

  // Use fetch `storage` from the bucket
  // https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample
  storageClient.bucket().getStorage().create(blob, 
      Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("backup/accounts.csv")));
} catch (IOException e) {
  logger.error(">>>>> Message from Scheduled Job " + e);
}
```

I'm still unable to download the uploaded file on [Firebase Storage dashboard](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/storage/), but the uploaded file can be downloaded through [Google Cloud Storage dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser).